# I cannot send Gmail by google-apps-script code

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  if( sheet.getSheetName() != 'Sheet1' ) { 

    return 0;

  }
var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();

  if( selectedCell.getColumn() == 1) { 

    var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(0, 2);

    dateTimeCell.setValue('auto');

    GmailApp.sendEmail('12345@gmail.com', selectedCell.getRow(), 'hello')

}
```

if I modify column A and run script, Gmail sent.
but if I modify column A only (don't run code), then Gmail not sent.
'auto' is inserted in both case. I suspect only GmailApp.sendEmail is not working.

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a trigger set up for it? The function you have only shows a simple trigger `onEdit()` which cannot send emails. [See Restrictions here.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

Answer (score 0):

Vytautas is right. It says that:

*They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the Language service, which is anonymous.*